# Kernel.org kernel config options different from Ubuntu ones

Tags: kernel, make

After compiling Ubuntu kernels for a few days (quite a fun experience, I must say), I decided to finally plunge into some vanilla kernel goodness.

So far, so good. Downloaded the most recent (3.13-rc1) kernel from kernel.org, untared the source, copied my config file over, made a localmodconfig and went right into menuconfig.

Strangely enough, many options appear different from their Ubuntu brethren. For one, there is no option to add an arbitrary version string.

Is there any way I can enable all the options the Ubuntu config had to over?

Answer (score 5):

If you want *all* of the options that the Ubuntu patched kernel sources offer, then you need to apply all of the patches that Ubuntu applies to the kernel.  The easiest way to do this is to just download the kernel sources from the Ubuntu repos.

You can track the most recently Ubuntu patched kernel sources with

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-<release>.git
```